# Segger Embedded Studio can not watch struct variable

Tags: debugging, stm32

Debug STM32F103, can not watch struct variable, which displayed as array.

[image]

Comment: Segger Embedded Studio (software) does not have anything in common with segger-jlink (debug probe). Your problem is not related to the debug probe. Do not use unrelated tags. BTW SES is extremely bad and was using it only when I was programming NRF uCs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.